# Formatting a string containing currency and commas

Tags: python, dataframe, formatting, format

Does anyone know how I'd format this string (which is a column in a dataframe) to be a float so I can sort by the column please?

```
£880,000
£88,500
£850,000
£845,000
```

i.e. I want this to become

```
88,500
845,000
850,000
880,000
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'col' the column name.

If you just want to sort, **and keep as string**, you can use [`natsorted`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#sorting-a-pandas-dataframe):

```
from natsort import natsort_key
df.sort_values(by='col', key=natsort_key)

# OR

from natsort import natsort_keygen
df.sort_values(by='col', key=natsort_keygen())
```

output:

```
        col
1   £88,500
3  £845,000
2  £850,000
0  £880,000
```

If you want to convert to floats:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'].str.replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True))

df.sort_values(by='col')
```

output:

```
      col
1   88500
3  845000
2  850000
0  880000
```

If you want strings, you can use [`str.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.lstrip('£')
```

output:

```
       col
0  880,000
1   88,500
2  850,000
3  845,000
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - appreciate it! That's a start but how do I format it to be a number and then order it?

Comment: @Mensa23 I updated the answer in the meantime

Comment: you're a legend! thanks so much!